# Having trouble installing the PG gem

Tags: postgresql, rubygems

I'm trying this, [as the docs say](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/0.11.0/frames):

```
gem install pg --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/pg_config
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
```

But, that's obviously not working. Can anyone spot an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the other answer works, but I thought I'd point out that the instructions here did work if you're using bundler to manage gems:

http://devblog.vworkapp.com/post/403869225/install-pg-gem-via-bundler-on-osx-snow-leopard

install postgres from Mac Ports

```
sudo port install postgres84
```

Include the postgres binaries in the PATH environment variable

```
export PATH=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin:${PATH}
```

Then run bundle install with the all-important arch flag

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install
```

Caveats: Your ARCHFLAGS may be something like i386 and not x86_64, depending on your local environment (and these instructions are obviously installing an older postgres -- I did `sudo port install postgresql90`).

Answer (score 1):

The example that you're linking to says this:

```
gem install -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
#-----------^^
```

Note the `--` in there that you're not using. I suspect that `gem` is trying to parse the `--with-pg-config` as an option to `gem` rather than an option to the gem itself. Just a plain `--` in an option list means "stop parsing options here" so try one of these:

```
gem install -- pg --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/pg_config
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/pg_config
```

One of those should keep `gem` from trying to interpret `--with-pg-config` as a `gem` option and get it down to the pg gem itself.

Comment: Yeah, I was really thrown off by those -- , but I found that providing the option to bundle install worked, though. The instructions here seem to be spot on: http://devblog.vworkapp.com/post/403869225/install-pg-gem-via-bundler-on-osx-snow-leopard